# Collection-repeat is cutting the last item

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, co

I have a collection-repeat like this (see the code below) and works fine, but the last item does not show well when the user scroll down.

Why could resolve this?

```
<ion-content on-scroll="moreItens()" style="margin-top:60px;  min-height: 600px;" overflow-scroll=”true” has-bouncing="true"  style="padding:2%;">
<!-- <div class="list"> -->
<div class="card card-1 border-card item my-item"
    collection-item-width="'100%'"
    collection-item-height="'150px'"
    force-refresh-images="true"

    id="list_ticket"
    collection-repeat="ticket in ticketCtrl.tickets | filter:ticket_cod || ticket_codP | limitTo:numberDisplay : numberBegin"  item="ticket"
    ng-class="ticketCtrl.getClass(ticket[2])">

    <a class="ticket-detalhes"><a class="infoTitle">Status: </a><a >{{ticketCtrl.getRole(ticket[2])}}</br></a>    
    <a class="ticket-detalhes"><a class="infoTitle">Data: </a>{{ticket[4]}}</a>    
    <a class="ticket-detalhes" ng-if="!setVisible(ticket[6])"><a ng-if="!setVisible(ticket[6])" class="infoTitle" >Motivo: </a>{{ticket[6]}}</br></a>
    <a class="infoTitle">Protocolo:</a> {{ticket[1]}}

    <div class="w3-btn-group " style="margin-bottom:1px; margin-top:10px; " >
        <button ng-click="setInteracao(ticket)" class="w3-btn button-footer ion-plus-circled"></button>
        <button id="btn_chat_ticket"  ng-click="openChat(ticket)" class="w3-btn button-footer ion-chatbubbles"></button>
        <a id="call" ng-href="{{call}}" class="w3-btn button-footer ion-android-call"></a>
        <button ng-click="ticketCtrl.getTicket(ticket)" class="w3-btn button-footer ion-more"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen even if you remove all filters ?

Comment: Yes, still happen without filters

Comment: Which version of ionic are you using ?

Comment: I had multiple issues with collection-repeat I had to set heights on container / scroll to get it working properly

Comment: I am currently using version 1.0.0 beta14

Comment: Thank you, stackg91. I followed your suggestion, but when I put height in the ion-container the items cease to appear. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Hey Arthur this is what i did <div class="item my-item"
      collection-repeat="item in items"
      collection-item-width="'100%'"
      collection-item-height="getItemHeight(item, $index)"
      ng-style="{height: getItemHeight(item, $index)}">
      {{item}}
</div>


 $scope.getItemHeight = function(item, index) {
    //Make evenly indexed items be 10px taller, for the sake of example
    return (index % 2) === 0 ? 50 : 60;
  };